# Nativescript Android build: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, angular, webpack, build, nativescript

I'm trying to create new Android app with Nativescript Angular, build passes ok, but when I try to run it on my device I get an error:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{<my-app-id>/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'com/tns/NativeScriptActivity'
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'com/tns/NativeScriptActivity'
    at com.tns.Runtime.createJSInstanceNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.createJSInstance(Runtime.java:643)
    at com.tns.Runtime.initInstance(Runtime.java:618)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.<init>(NativeScriptActivity.java:12)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
    ... 9 more
```

Reproduction steps:

```
cd elipay-builds
tns create MyApp --appid <my-app-id> --template ng
cd MyApp

npm install --save-dev nativescript-dev-webpack
npm install
./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs --deps

tns run android
tns build android --bundle
```

---

UPDATE 1: I managed to figure out that an issue is somehow connected to the `applicationId`.

UPDATE 2: If I update `id` property in my nativescript's `package.json` file:

```
{
    ...
    "nativescript": {
        "id": "<my-new-app-id>"
    },
    ...
}
```

I need to assign new applicationId to my app each time I build it. And this is wrong, since stores will recognize my app as different one after the update.

---

I don't know what else I can try. Please help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: under App_Resources/Android locate app.gradle  and change the application id

Comment: I thought that this is done automatically by hooks when app is build. Can you give me more insights?

Comment: There is bug request in https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2089 & https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2367

Comment: @vcs thank you, those two issues really helped me understand why this error occures. I’ll try your solution. Thanks again